# Uso de ${variable} en lenguaje JS con VSCode

Tags: javascript, html5, vscode

Estoy intentando insertar una variable que tengo en JS en una hoja HTML, pero no consigo que me funcione usando el comando: **${nombre}** dentro de un .innerHTML

```js
const contenido = document.getElementById
("contenido");

let nombre = "Dani El";

contenido.innerHTML = '<h2> ${nombre} </h2>';
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Aprendiendo JS</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hola programadores</h1>
    <div id="contenido"></div>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Alquien me sabría decir porqué no me funciona usando los apóstrofes?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2):

Ya encontré el fallo... se trata de usar `tildes` y no 'apóstrofes'.

```js
const contenido = document.getElementById
("contenido");

let nombre = "Dani El";

contenido.innerHTML =`<h2> ${nombre} </h2>`;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Aprendiendo JS</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hola programadores</h1>
    <div id="contenido"></div>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Me alegra que encontraras la solución tú mismo . p¡Por cierto, los textos entre backticks ( ` )  se llama literales de cadena.

Comment: template literals